# Azure AD-Connect Group Writeback no import

Tags: azure, azure-connect

I'm working out some use-cases with the GA release of AzureAD-Connect. One feature we're interested in is the new writeback functionality. We've activated both user and group writeback in the Azure AD Connect  sync options. The user writeback works great, imported some users from WAAD and scope filtered them some some are synced and exported to ADDS. However there are no Groups imported into the connector space of the WAAD-MA, so I cannot do or troubleshoot anything with it. Is there a way to see why the WAAD Groups are not imported by the MA? Or what could the reason be that WAAD Groups are not imported?

Regards,

Joris

Answer (score 0):

Group writeback is only used for the new "Office365 Groups" group-type. You cannot sync back the other Groups you create in AzureAD.